# Отображение файлов архива

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Как сделать отображение списка файлов, находящихся в архиве открытый пользователем (наподобие проводника)?

Comment: что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Я просто не в курсе как можно сделать отображение списка файлов открытого архива

Comment: У вас должно быть API к формату архива. Разбирать архив вручную — длинная и неблагодарная работа.

Comment: А если без API, то как можно подобное реализовать?

Comment: @user222335: Ууууууххх. Вам понадобится описание формата архива, оно должно по идее где-нибудь найтись. Ну и дальше вам придётся вручную разбирать бинарный файл согласно формату. Общих рекомендаций нет, формат может быть каким угодно, всё зависит лишь от причуд автора формата.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь))

Comment: Как вариант использовать 7zip для открытия архивов, если под архивом имеется ввиду что-то из стандартного зоопарка. Запускаете консольный вариант с редиректом стандартного вывода и парсите вывод как вам нравится. Минус - нужен 7zip, но он вроде бы умеет работать без установки в систему.

Comment: Для обычных ZIP есть пространства имен в стандартной библиотеке, например класс `ZipArchive`

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для Zip архива можно сделать так:

```
using System.IO.Compression;
//
string[] filesnames;
using (var fstream = File.Open(PathTextBox.Text, FileMode.Open))
{
    var arch = new ZipArchive(fstream);
    filesnames = arch.Entries.Select(s => s.Name).ToArray();
}
```

Перед этим добавив ссылку на `System.IO.Compression`.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wONxrfl.png